# Finding outliers on a scatter plot

Tags: outliers, scatterplot

I have a set of data points that are supposed to sit on a locus and follow a pattern, but there are some scatter points from the main locus that cause uncertainty in my final analysis. I would like to obtain a neat locus to apply it later for my analysis. The blue points are more or less the scatter points that I want to find and exclude them by a sophisticated way without doing it manually.[image]

I was thinking of using something like Nearest Neighbors Regression but I am not sure whether it is the best approach or I am not very familiar how it should be implemented in order to give me an appropriate result. By the way, I want to do it without any fitting procedure.

The transposed version of the data is a following:

```
X=array([[ 0.87 , -0.01 ,  0.575,  1.212,  0.382,  0.418, -0.01 ,  0.474,
         0.432,  0.702,  0.574,  0.45 ,  0.334,  0.565,  0.414,  0.873,
         0.381,  1.103,  0.848,  0.503,  0.27 ,  0.416,  0.939,  1.211,
         1.106,  0.321,  0.709,  0.744,  0.309,  0.247,  0.47 , -0.107,
         0.925,  1.127,  0.833,  0.963,  0.385,  0.572,  0.437,  0.577,
         0.461,  0.474,  1.046,  0.892,  0.313,  1.009,  1.048,  0.349,
         1.189,  0.302,  0.278,  0.629,  0.36 ,  1.188,  0.273,  0.191,
        -0.068,  0.95 ,  1.044,  0.776,  0.726,  1.035,  0.817,  0.55 ,
         0.387,  0.476,  0.473,  0.863,  0.252,  0.664,  0.365,  0.244,
         0.238,  1.203,  0.339,  0.528,  0.326,  0.347,  0.385,  1.139,
         0.748,  0.879,  0.324,  0.265,  0.328,  0.815,  0.38 ,  0.884,
         0.571,  0.416,  0.485,  0.683,  0.496,  0.488,  1.204,  1.18 ,
         0.465,  0.34 ,  0.335,  0.447,  0.28 ,  1.02 ,  0.519,  0.335,
         1.037,  1.126,  0.323,  0.452,  0.201,  0.321,  0.285,  0.587,
         0.292,  0.228,  0.303,  0.844,  0.229,  1.077,  0.864,  0.515,
         0.071,  0.346,  0.255,  0.88 ,  0.24 ,  0.533,  0.725,  0.339,
         0.546,  0.841,  0.43 ,  0.568,  0.311,  0.401,  0.212,  0.691,
         0.565,  0.292,  0.295,  0.587,  0.545,  0.817,  0.324,  0.456,
         0.267,  0.226,  0.262,  0.338,  1.124,  0.373,  0.814,  1.241,
         0.661,  0.229,  0.416,  1.103,  0.226,  1.168,  0.616,  0.593,
         0.803,  1.124,  0.06 ,  0.573,  0.664,  0.882,  0.286,  0.139,
         1.095,  1.112,  1.167,  0.589,  0.3  ,  0.578,  0.727,  0.252,
         0.174,  0.317,  0.427,  1.184,  0.397,  0.43 ,  0.229,  0.261,
         0.632,  0.938,  0.576,  0.37 ,  0.497,  0.54 ,  0.306,  0.315,
         0.335,  0.24 ,  0.344,  0.93 ,  0.134,  0.4  ,  0.223,  1.224,
         1.187,  1.031,  0.25 ,  0.53 , -0.147,  0.087,  0.374,  0.496,
         0.441,  0.884,  0.971,  0.749,  0.432,  0.582,  0.198,  0.615,
         1.146,  0.475,  0.595,  0.304,  0.416,  0.645,  0.281,  0.576,
         1.139,  0.316,  0.892,  0.648,  0.826,  0.299,  0.381,  0.926,
         0.606],
       [-0.154, -0.392, -0.262,  0.214, -0.403, -0.363, -0.461, -0.326,
        -0.349, -0.21 , -0.286, -0.358, -0.436, -0.297, -0.394, -0.166,
        -0.389,  0.029, -0.124, -0.335, -0.419, -0.373, -0.121,  0.358,
         0.042, -0.408, -0.189, -0.213, -0.418, -0.479, -0.303, -0.645,
        -0.153,  0.098, -0.171, -0.066, -0.368, -0.273, -0.329, -0.295,
        -0.362, -0.305, -0.052, -0.171, -0.406, -0.102,  0.011, -0.375,
         0.126, -0.411, -0.42 , -0.27 , -0.407,  0.144, -0.419, -0.465,
        -0.036, -0.099,  0.007, -0.167, -0.205, -0.011, -0.151, -0.267,
        -0.368, -0.342, -0.299, -0.143, -0.42 , -0.232, -0.368, -0.417,
        -0.432,  0.171, -0.388, -0.319, -0.407, -0.379, -0.353,  0.043,
        -0.211, -0.14 , -0.373, -0.431, -0.383, -0.142, -0.345, -0.144,
        -0.302, -0.38 , -0.337, -0.2  , -0.321, -0.269,  0.406,  0.223,
        -0.322, -0.395, -0.379, -0.324, -0.424,  0.01 , -0.298, -0.386,
         0.018,  0.157, -0.384, -0.327, -0.442, -0.388, -0.387, -0.272,
        -0.397, -0.415, -0.388, -0.106, -0.504,  0.034, -0.153, -0.32 ,
        -0.271, -0.417, -0.417, -0.136, -0.447, -0.279, -0.225, -0.372,
        -0.316, -0.161, -0.331, -0.261, -0.409, -0.338, -0.437, -0.242,
        -0.328, -0.403, -0.433, -0.274, -0.331, -0.163, -0.361, -0.298,
        -0.392, -0.447, -0.429, -0.388,  0.11 , -0.348, -0.174,  0.244,
        -0.182, -0.424, -0.319,  0.088, -0.547,  0.189, -0.216, -0.228,
        -0.17 ,  0.125, -0.073, -0.266, -0.234, -0.108, -0.395, -0.395,
         0.131,  0.074,  0.514, -0.235, -0.389, -0.288, -0.22 , -0.416,
        -0.777, -0.358, -0.31 ,  0.817, -0.363, -0.328, -0.424, -0.416,
        -0.248, -0.093, -0.28 , -0.357, -0.348, -0.298, -0.384, -0.394,
        -0.362, -0.415, -0.349, -0.08 , -0.572, -0.07 , -0.423,  0.359,
         0.4  ,  0.099, -0.426, -0.252, -0.697, -0.508, -0.348, -0.254,
        -0.307, -0.116, -0.029, -0.201, -0.302, -0.25 , -0.44 , -0.233,
         0.274, -0.295, -0.223, -0.398, -0.298, -0.209, -0.389, -0.247,
         0.225, -0.395, -0.124, -0.237, -0.104, -0.361, -0.335, -0.083,
        -0.254]])
```

Comment: How are you identifying those blue points?

Comment: @Dan Just put some limits on `x` and `y` and determined them. But I have a lot of this kind of plots with different features and different scatter points and I want to find a reliable way to exclude them without defining them by looking at the diagrams.

Comment: how do you define a "neat pattern".  I see no rationale for why those blue points would be excluded besides visual inspection.  If you had a criteria for exclusion it would make more sense.

Comment: @Dan based on the application I am looking for the blue points for me are considered as outliers and scatters from the main feature.

Comment: ok so then what defined the "main feature"?

Comment: @Dan Indeed! The main locus it is what I am interested.

Comment: I don't think this question is answerable without more detail.

Comment: @Dan what do you mean by more details? These are observational data from colors of stars. It is expected that they would be in a locus but there is no analytical reason how it should look like. It depends on the filters of the telescope and the properties of the stars and these scatter points are maybe due to miss classification of star/galaxy and I want to discard them with another ways.

Comment: @Dan I think the question is pretty clear and I don't understand why it is downvoted.

Comment: I didn't downvote the question

Comment: Your not telling us what defines a locus.  I (and I'm sure many others) have no idea why those red points define a locus.  If you could give more details on what a locus is and how those red points cluster together to do so then surely we could tell you how to discriminate between point ion the locus and not. That is why you question is not clear.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**As a start in identifying the "scattered" points, consider focusing on locations where a kernel density estimate is relatively low.**

This suggestion assumes little or nothing is known or even suspected initially about the "locus" of the points--the curve or curves along which most of them will fall--and it is made in the spirit of semi-automated exploration of the data (rather than testing of hypotheses).

You might need to play with the kernel width and the threshold of "relatively low".  There exist good automatic ways to estimate the former while the latter could be identified via an analysis of the densities at the data points (to identify a cluster of low values).

---

#### Example

The figure is generated a combination of two kinds of data: one, shown as red points, are high-precision data, while the other, shown as blue points, are relatively low-precision data obtained near the extreme low value of $X$.  In its background are (a) contours of a kernel density estimate (in grayscale) and (b) the curve around which the points were generated (in black).

[image: Figure]

The points with relatively low densities have been circled *automatically*.  (The densities at these points are less than one-eighth of the mean density among all points.)  They include most--but not all!--of the low-precision points and some of the high-precision points (at the top right).  Low-precision points lying near the curve (as extrapolated by the high-precision points) have not been circled.  The circling of the high-precision points highlights the fact that *wherever* points are sparse, the trace of the underlying curve will be uncertain.  This is a *feature* of the suggested approach, not a limitation!

---

#### Code

`R` code to produce this example follows.  It uses the `ks` library, which assesses anisotropy in the point pattern to develop an oriented kernel shape.  This approach works well in the sample data, whose point cloud tends to be long and skinny.

```r
#
# Simulate some data.
#
f <- function(x) -0.55 + 0.45*x + 0.01/(1.2-x)^2 # The underlying curve

set.seed(17)
n1 <- 280; n2 <- 15
x <- c(1.2 - rbeta(n1,.9, .6), rep(0.1, n2))
y <- f(x)
d <- data.frame(x=x + c(rnorm(n1, 0, 0.025), rnorm(n2, 0, 0.1)),
                   y=y + c(rnorm(n1, 0, 0.025), rnorm(n2, 0, 0.33)),
                   group=c(rep(1, n1), rep(2, n2)))
d <- subset(d, subset=(y <= 1.0)) # Omit any high-y points
#
# Plot the density estimate.
#
require(ks)
p <- cbind(d$x, d$y)
dens <- kde(p)
n.levels <- 13
colors <- gray(seq(1, 0, length.out=n.levels))
plot(dens, display="filled.contour2", cont=seq(0, 100, length.out=n.levels),
     col=colors, xlab="X", ylab="Y")
#
# Evaluate densities at the data points.
#
dens <- kde(p, eval.points=p)
d$Density <- dens$estimate
#
# Plot the (correct) curve and the points.
#
curve(f(x), add=TRUE, to=1.2, col="Black")
points(d$x, d$y, ylim=c(-1,1), pch=19, cex=sqrt(d$Density/8),
     col=ifelse(d$group==1, "Red", "Blue"))
#
# Highlight some low-density points.
#
m <- mean(d$Density)
e <- subset(d, subset=(Density < m/10))
points(e$x, e$y, col="#00000080")
```

Comment: The reason simulated data are provided is that I did this analysis before the data were posted in the question.  The simulation code can be useful for testing this--or any other--procedure, though, and so might be useful in its own right.

Comment: in order to get the underlying curve, so you estimated the coefficient of the fit by using a fitting procedure,right? have you assumed any function for fitting?

Comment: None whatsoever: see the code, which uses only the kernel density estimate (as returned by `kde`) to identify points to be circled. If I had not simulated the data from a known functional form (as given by `f`), I would not have been able to draw any reference curve at all, because no fitting was done.

Comment: I meant the functionality of `f(x)`.

Comment: @whuber, super cool plot!

Comment: @whuber It seems exactly what I was looking for, but since I am not very familiar with `R`, I will be really grateful if you would document it more. Then I can transfer it to python. Thanks again.

Comment: @whuber I concur with Dan's statement. The plot is very cool!

Comment: You would need to find the Python equivalent of the `ks` package. Documentation for `ks` can be found through links at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ks/index.html. Apart from that, there's nothing else going on here: everything is done in just a few simple lines of code. `dens <- kde(p, eval.points=p)` computes the density at the data points. These are copied into a new `Density` variable via `d$Density <- dens$estimate`. The low-density points are screened by finding the mean density `m <- mean(d$Density)` and applying the criterion `Density < m/10`.

Comment: @whuber It seems more than one `kde` has been used, am I right? How do you estimate how many you might need?

Comment: No, only one was used. As the comments explain, the function had to be called twice: first to produce the density plot and then to output the density estimates at the data points themselves. (To create the filled contours, density estimates had to be computed at points on a regular grid covering the entire plot. You do not need to do that unless you want to generate a similar plot.) The *only* parts of the code you actually need are the `Evaluate densities at the data points` and `Highlight some low-density points`, as explained in my preceding comment.