# Bivariate Kernel Density plot

Tags: r, data-visualization, scatterplot

Suppose that I have two variables, $X$ and $Y$ that I want to correlate, i.e. in the manner of a scatterplot of $(X_i,Y_i)$. But I also want to show the density of each variable. A scatterplot basically does this, but I wanted a more organic display in the fashion of a KDE.

How can I make a plot where $\mathrm{dens}(x,y) = K(X,x,Y,y)$? I imagine plotting $\mathrm{dens}(x,y)$ either as a third variable with a 3D design if the distributions are simple or as pixel color intensity/value.

A sample kernel in this example would be the product of the KDEs for each respective variable.

A motivating example would be to observe bivariate "islands" in heteroscedastic data.

Comment: Something like this? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:MultivariateNormal.png

Comment: @Benjamin Not really. Picture a scatterplot except with a properly sized 2D normal distribution superimposed on each point. (shading is fine)

Comment: ggplot2 can do this using `stat_density2d`: https://www.google.com/search?q=ggplot+stat_density2d&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=cyI-VIvKMdDzarCbgPgH&ved=0CAgQ_AUoAQ&biw=1920&bih=1078

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for something like the image I posted in an answer at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/114238, which superimposes the scatterplot over a KDE of the bivariate data with two more (discrete) variables symbolized by color and symbol type. The post includes `R` code to produce the figure.

Answer (score 1):

Package `ggplot2` can do this using `stat_density2d`, see [the documentation](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/stat_density2d.html).

[image]

Comment: Also see the overlaid contours on the scatterplot in the documentation link provided above!