# 95% region from a bivariate density

Tags: density-function, kernel-smoothing

I have a bivariate data which can be displayed as a scatterplot of which marginal distribution is Uniform(0,1).
Using 'kde2d' function in R, I can also obtain two-dimensional density of these data.
What I would like to get is a contour line (actually an area rather than a line) of density that includes 95% of the entire observations.
I'd like to represent this area by 0-1 variables on a grid.
That is,

```
x1 = x2 = seq(0.01,0.99,0.01)
x12 = expand.grid(x1,x2)
z = (a vector of length 9801(99*99) which consists of indicator variables 
whether this grid point is included in the 95% region)
```

How can I get this vector z?

Comment: The code in my answer at http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/114238 should get you almost all the way there.  But are you asking to estimate a region that contains 95% of the *density* or 95% of the *observations*?

Comment: - How are they different? If a region contains 95% of the density, doesn't it contain approx. 95% of the observations?
- Your code gives the points where the density is less than 1/10 of mean density, but not x percent of observations, right?

Comment: It depends a little bit on the bandwidth used to compute the density. With a sufficiently narrow bandwidth you will find 100% of the points located within the contour containing 95% of the integrated density.  With a sufficiently broad bandwidth you will again find 100% of the points within that contour.